# How to specify margin by screen size in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a wider margin for medium or wider screens, but a narrower margin for small screens.

`<div class="mx-sm-1 mx-md-5">content</div>`

It works for medium or wider screens. But small screens get a zero margin with this. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is a JSFiddle. 575px width or below has zero margin.

https://jsfiddle.net/3kdrxng6/2/

Comment: It's working for me. Could you create a jsfiddle so that we will all see your problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `mx-1` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margins of size extra small (which is what I assume you are going for) don't need the middle notation. `mx-1` should work instead.

`<div class="mx-1 mx-md-5">content</div>`